# unable to access helloworld App deployed using DCOS Marathon in Azure

Tags: azure, docker, marathon, dcos, azure-container-service

I have deployed a hello world application in Azure using DCOS and Marathon Framework.I am trying to access that using fqn: portnumber at which the application is hosted. I am unable to open the application

Following is the json I have used

```html
{
  "id": "/dockercloud-hello-world",
  "cmd": null,
  "cpus": 0.1,
  "mem": 128,
  "disk": 0,
  "instances": 2,
  "acceptedResourceRoles": [
    "*"
  ],
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "volumes": [],
    "docker": {
      "image": "dockercloud/hello-world",
      "network": "BRIDGE",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "hostPort": 0,
          "servicePort": 10000,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "labels": {}
        }
      ],
      "privileged": false,
      "parameters": [],
      "forcePullImage": true
    }
  },
  "healthChecks": [
    {
      "gracePeriodSeconds": 10,
      "intervalSeconds": 2,
      "timeoutSeconds": 10,
      "maxConsecutiveFailures": 10,
      "portIndex": 0,
      "path": "/",
      "protocol": "HTTP",
      "ignoreHttp1xx": false
    }
  ],
  "portDefinitions": [
    {
      "port": 10000,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "name": "default",
      "labels": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

I have added NSG Inbound rule for master nsg resource
I have added NAT rule for master lb resource allowing the port as custom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `host port` is 0, Azure will listen your service on a random port. You need open the port on NSG and lb.

I suggest you could specify the port, you could check the following example:

```
{
  "id": "/dockercloud-hello-world",
  "cmd": null,
  "cpus": 0.1,
  "mem": 32,
  "disk": 0,
  "instances": 1,
  "acceptedResourceRoles": [
    "slave_public"
  ],
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "volumes": [],
    "docker": {
      "image": "dockercloud/hello-world",
      "network": "BRIDGE",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "hostPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "labels": {},
          "name": "test80"
        }
      ],
      "privileged": false,
      "parameters": [],
      "forcePullImage": true
    }
  },
  "healthChecks": [
    {
      "gracePeriodSeconds": 10,
      "intervalSeconds": 2,
      "timeoutSeconds": 10,
      "maxConsecutiveFailures": 10,
      "portIndex": 0,
      "path": "/",
      "protocol": "MESOS_HTTP",
      "ignoreHttp1xx": false
    }
  ],
  "requirePorts": true
}
```

Note: You should set `acceptedResourceRoles` to `slave_public`. More information about this please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/dcos-swarm/container-service-mesos-marathon-ui).

Comment: I tried changing hostport to 80. It is unable to deploy application

Comment: Yes, I meet same error, but I modify you json file. You could copy my json, it will work.

Comment: You need add ` "acceptedResourceRoles": [
    "slave_public"
  ],`

Comment: This is my test result https://imgur.com/a/x7BB9 I suggest you could try.

Comment: I have copied the json provided in the comment that did not even deploy application

Comment: If possible, could you copy all of the json file. I notice, there are mistakes in your json file, for example `healthChecks` is not effective

Comment: I check it, it seems it is same with my json file? Do you get some error log?

Comment: Another question, do you use Azure Container Service(DC/OS)?

Comment: Yes. I am using Azure Container Service (DC/OS)
No it is not getting deployed . I dont have any log
https://jsfiddle.net/rxp5zhtk/

Comment: It is very strange, the json file works for me fine.  You could check this 
   http://shuidcagents.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com/

Comment: Any rules we need to add for this. I have http and https enabled apart from the rules given by azure. I cant even deploy so i am not sure what i need to add

Comment: What do you mean `I have http and https enabled apart from the rules given by azure.`? If possible, could you show some screenshot about your marathon UI?

Comment: I have a difference with you. I use a tunnle to connect DC/OS https://imgur.com/a/zvtaF

Comment: But I suggest you could create a container by using UI not json file, like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/dcos-swarm/container-service-mesos-marathon-ui#deploy-a-docker-formatted-container

Comment: You only need to modify image, I test in my lab, it really works for me.

Comment: I am able to deploy when I tunnel it. But if I use my fqn it is going to dcos ui...
https://imgur.com/a/rQOjX

Comment: According to Azure's official document, Azure suggest us using tunnel it and create a container.

Comment: I think it is not security to expose the UI on the Internet, I test it in my lab, I could not access your UI without authentication. I suggest you should not open port 80 on master VM's NSG.

Comment: I am still unable to see the UI. that you are able to look at

Comment: I have not allowed 80 in master NSG and UI is not exposed now. It is removed. still i am unable to access using master fqn. Now i am getting This site can’t be reached error

Comment: @user2547194 You should use agent FQDN to access the service, not master ip. Like this `http://shuidcagents.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com/`

Comment: The master IP is like `shuidcmgmt.***`, the agent IP is like `shuidcagent.***`. You should use agent IP to access your service.

Comment: Do you deploy the image, you should access `http://ggktechagent.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com/`

Comment: Can we have application hosted at different ports other than 80? How

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But you need open port on Azure NSG and LB

Comment: For master or agent ... is it a custom port ?

Comment: You should open port on agent VM. You don't need open other port on master node. Master is just a management console. The service is running on agent node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166237/discussion-between-user2547194-and-shengbao-shui-msft).

Answer (score 1):

Along with the above-mentioned JSON I need to use the agent URL to access the application. I was missing on that